# How to project PyBullet simulation coordinates to rendered Frame pixel coordinates using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, graphics, pybullet

How can I convert an objects position in PyBullet to pixel coordinates & draw a line onto the frame using PyBullet & OpenCV?

We would like to do this because PyBullet native `addUserDebugLine()` function is not available in DIRECT mode.

```
import pybullet as p
import numpy as np
import time
import pybullet_data
import cv2


VIDEO_RESOLUTION = (1280, 720)
MY_COLORS = [(255,0,0), (0,255,0), (0,0,255)]
def capture_frame(base_pos=[0,0,0], _cam_dist=3, _cam_yaw=45, _cam_pitch=-45):
        _render_width, _render_height = VIDEO_RESOLUTION
        view_matrix = p.computeViewMatrixFromYawPitchRoll(
            cameraTargetPosition=base_pos,
            distance=_cam_dist,
            yaw=_cam_yaw,
            pitch=_cam_pitch,
            roll=0,
            upAxisIndex=2)
        proj_matrix = p.computeProjectionMatrixFOV(
            fov=90, aspect=float(_render_width) / _render_height,
            nearVal=0.01, farVal=100.0)
        (_, _, px, _, _) = p.getCameraImage(
            width=_render_width, height=_render_height, viewMatrix=view_matrix,
            projectionMatrix=proj_matrix, renderer=p.ER_TINY_RENDERER)  # ER_BULLET_HARDWARE_OPENGL)
        rgb_array = np.array(px, dtype=np.uint8)
        rgb_array = np.reshape(rgb_array, (_render_height, _render_width, 4))
        rgb_array = rgb_array[:, :, :3]
        return rgb_array, view_matrix, proj_matrix
def render():
    frame, vmat, pmat = capture_frame()
    p1, cubeOrn = p.getBasePositionAndOrientation(1)
    p2, cubeOrn = p.getBasePositionAndOrientation(2)
    frame, view_matrix,  proj_matrix = capture_frame()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, VIDEO_RESOLUTION)
    points = {}

    # reshape matrices
    my_order = 'C'
    pmat = np.array(proj_matrix).reshape((4,4), order=my_order)
    vmat = np.array(view_matrix).reshape((4,4), order=my_order)
    fmat = vmat.T @ pmat.T

    # compute origin from origin point in simulation
    origin = np.array([0,0,0,1])
    frame_origin = (fmat @ origin)[:3]*np.array([1280, 640, 0]) + np.array([640, 360, 0])

    # define unit vectors
    unit_vectors = [ np.array([1,0,0,1]),
                     np.array([0,1,0,1]), 
                     np.array([0,0,1,1]) ]

    for col_id, unit_vector in enumerate(unit_vectors):
        cur_point = (fmat @ unit_vector)[:3]*np.array([1280, 640, 0]) + np.array([640, 360, 0])
        cv2.line(frame, (640,360), (int(cur_point[0]),int(cur_point[1])), color=MY_COLORS[col_id], thickness=2)
    cv2.imwrite("my_rendering.jpg", frame)
    print(p1,p2)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    physicsClient = p.connect(p.DIRECT)#or p.DIRECT for non-graphical version
    p.setAdditionalSearchPath(pybullet_data.getDataPath()) #optionally
    p.setGravity(0,0,-10)
    planeId = p.loadURDF("plane.urdf")
    startPos = [1,0,0.2]
    startOrientation = p.getQuaternionFromEuler([0,0,0])
    boxId = p.loadURDF("r2d2.urdf",startPos, startOrientation)
    startPos = [0,2,0.2]
    boxId = p.loadURDF("r2d2.urdf",startPos, startOrientation)
    #set the center of mass frame (loadURDF sets base link frame) startPos/Ornp.resetBasePositionAndOrientation(boxId, startPos, startOrientation)
    for i in range (2400):
        if i == 2399:
            render()
        p.stepSimulation()


    p.disconnect()
```

The expected output would be the following frame but with the origin-coordinate frame drawn correctly. E.g. X, Y, and Z axis are colored Red, Blue, and Green respectively.

Since the two R2D2 robots are positioned at [1,0,0] and [0,1,0] respectively, we can see that the coordinate frame is off. (See image below)
[image]

We tried the following:

- transposing the matrices
- not transposing the matrices
- changing the order of how we compute fmat e.g. pmat @ vmat instead of vmat @ pmat etc.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @S_Bersier You are right, almost as if changing the aspect ratio would distort the picture in a way that the cv2 plotted lines don't capture. So what transformation would be needed on those lines so the aspect ratio change would be reflected in the drawn axes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of fiddling, I came to a solution.
Playing with it for a while, I came to a point where it looked almost OK except for a rotation of the axes given by the yaw angle. So, I did a second call to computeViewMatrixFromYawPitchRoll but with the opposite yaw in order to compute the transformation for the axes.
Unfortunately, I'm not sure about why this works... But it works!
Note: base_pos, _cam_dist, _cam_yaw and _cam_pitch have been displaced into render() Note also: the up direction has been reversed too (don't ask why... :-) ) A pretty messy explanation, I must admit...

```
import pybullet as p
import numpy as np
import time
import pybullet_data
import cv2
import os

VIDEO_RESOLUTION = (1280, 720)
MY_COLORS = [(255,0,0), (0,255,0), (0,0,255)]
K=np.array([[1280,0,0],[0,720,0],[0,0,1]])

def capture_frame(base_pos, _cam_dist, _cam_yaw, _cam_pitch):
        _render_width, _render_height = VIDEO_RESOLUTION
        view_matrix = p.computeViewMatrixFromYawPitchRoll(
            cameraTargetPosition=base_pos,
            distance=_cam_dist,
            yaw=_cam_yaw,
            pitch=_cam_pitch,
            roll=0,
            upAxisIndex=2)
        proj_matrix = p.computeProjectionMatrixFOV(
            fov=90, aspect=float(_render_width) / _render_height,
            nearVal=0.01, farVal=100.0)
        (_, _, px, _, _) = p.getCameraImage(
            width=_render_width, height=_render_height, viewMatrix=view_matrix,
            projectionMatrix=proj_matrix, renderer=p.ER_TINY_RENDERER)  # ER_BULLET_HARDWARE_OPENGL)
        rgb_array = np.array(px, dtype=np.uint8)
        rgb_array = np.reshape(rgb_array, (_render_height, _render_width, 4))
        rgb_array = rgb_array[:, :, :3]
        return rgb_array, view_matrix, proj_matrix
def render():
    p1, cubeOrn = p.getBasePositionAndOrientation(1)
    p2, cubeOrn = p.getBasePositionAndOrientation(2)
    base_pos=[0,0,0]
    _cam_dist=3
    _cam_yaw=45
    _cam_pitch=-30
    frame, view_matrix,  proj_matrix = capture_frame(base_pos, _cam_dist, _cam_yaw, _cam_pitch)
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, VIDEO_RESOLUTION)
    points = {}

    # inverse transform
    view_matrix = p.computeViewMatrixFromYawPitchRoll(
        cameraTargetPosition=base_pos,
        distance=_cam_dist,
        yaw=-_cam_yaw,
        pitch=_cam_pitch,
        roll=0,
        upAxisIndex=2)    
    

    my_order = 'C'
    pmat = np.array(proj_matrix).reshape((4,4), order=my_order)
    vmat = np.array(view_matrix).reshape((4,4), order=my_order)

    fmat = pmat @ vmat.T

    # compute origin from origin point in simulation
    origin = np.array([0,0,0,1])
    frame_origin = (fmat @ origin)[:3]*np.array([1280, 720, 0]) + np.array([640, 360, 0])

    # define unit vectors
    unit_vectors = [ np.array([1,0,0,1]),
                     np.array([0,1,0,1]), 
                     np.array([0,0,-1,1]) ]  

    for col_id, unit_vector in enumerate(unit_vectors):
        cur_point = (fmat @ unit_vector)[:3]*np.array([1280, 720, 0]) + np.array([640, 360, 0])
        cv2.line(frame, (640,360), (int(cur_point[0]),int(cur_point[1])), color=MY_COLORS[col_id], thickness=2)
    cv2.imwrite("my_rendering.jpg", frame)
    print(p1,p2)
if __name__ == '__main__':

    physicsClient = p.connect(p.DIRECT)#or p.DIRECT for non-graphical version
    #physicsClient = p.connect(p.GUI)#or p.DIRECT for non-graphical version
    p.setAdditionalSearchPath(pybullet_data.getDataPath()) #optionally
    p.setGravity(0,0,-10)
    planeId = p.loadURDF("plane.urdf")
    #arrows = p.loadURDF("arrows.urdf")

    startPos = [1,0,0.2]
    startOrientation = p.getQuaternionFromEuler([0,0,0])
    boxId = p.loadURDF("r2d2.urdf",startPos, startOrientation)
    startPos = [0,2,0.2]
    boxId = p.loadURDF("r2d2.urdf",startPos, startOrientation)
    #set the center of mass frame (loadURDF sets base link frame) startPos/Ornp.resetBasePositionAndOrientation(boxId, startPos, startOrientation)
    for i in range (2400):
        if i == 2399:
            render()
        p.stepSimulation()

    p.disconnect()
```

Here is the result:
Best regards.
[image]

Comment: PS: You can  change the y-unit vector direction by putting: np.array([0,-1,0,1]) instead of np.array([0,1,0,1]) in the unit_vector definition.

Comment: Thank you, this works flawlessly for all resolutions.  It really looks like the representation inside PyBullet doesn't match OpenCV convention. This was very helpful. Maybe somebody knows what the difference in representation is, so we can add an explanation to this solution.

Comment: Indeed, in the examples provided with pybullet, I could'nt find an example which makes use of opencv. This said, it might be possible to draw simple line segments directly with pybullet. But I couldn't find how to do that. This would be the simplest way.

Comment: there is a way to add lines in PyBullet via "pybullet.addUserDebugLine", however, this method only works if the GUI is enabled, and is thus not suited for what we need it for.

Comment: Another possibility could be to create an urdf object (like the plane) which consists in the 3 arrows/lines and to add it to the scene. I tried that too, without success.  :-(